# How to avoid many allocations of the same string?

Tags: ruby

The following code should(?) allocate one "prefix:foo" and one "foo" string accordingly to [an article from SamSaffron](https://discuss.samsaffron.com/t/reducing-string-duplication-in-ruby/394) and his [pr into rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32016). I have implemented basically the same technique (with minus sign) but didn't see any differences.
I'm using ruby 2.5.0. The same is with 2.6.

Simple toy example to show the point:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "memory_profiler"

def remove_prefix(str)
  -str.sub(/.*prefix:/, "") # notice '-' here
end

report = MemoryProfiler.report do
  str = "prefix:foo"

  1000.times do
    remove_prefix(str)
  end
end

report.pretty_print
```

Result:

```
Allocated String Report
-----------------------------------
      1000  "foo"
      1000  memory.rb:6

      1000  "prefix:foo"
      1000  memory.rb:6
```

What's wrong with that code? Or how can (if can) I avoid many allocations of the same string?

Comment: Sorry I have to ask the dumb question since you didn't state: what version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: @lurker 2.5.0 and 2.6